# Cannot return correct JSON value

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've been trying to return a certain value in the data that I receive when processing JSON data but I can't seem to get the certain value. I can only get all of the information. Here's the problem in greater detail:

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

lazy var data = NSMutableData()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    startConnection()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func startConnection(){
    let urlPath: String = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/soon2challenger?api_key=(removed my private API key for obvious reasons)"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.start()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!){
    startConnection()
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError
    // throwing an error on the line below (can't figure out where the error message is)
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    println(jsonResult)
  }
}
```

The code works fine. This is the result I get.

```
{
soon2challenger =     {
    id = 43993167;
    name = soon2challenger;
    profileIconId = 844;
    revisionDate = 1435549418000;
    summonerLevel = 30;
   };
}
```

The problem is that when I want to return a certain value from the list, as in the id, I can't seem to do that. I tried doing println(jsonResult["id"]) but that just results in nil.

How can I return a certain value from the list? Ex. id, name, profileIconId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `objectForKey` like so:

```
let inside = jsonResult.objectForKey("soon2challenger")
```

Now you have extracted the soon2challenger object. Then you can easily get values:

```
print(include.objectForKey("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a value inside a sub-array.  The previous poster is correct; after getting the sub-array you can use array["id"];